# XSL Transformation - Remove empty elements for specific element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have written a XSL code for removing empty elements which do not have any attributes from any xml file. If the empty element has an attribute, I don't want to remove that element.
Eg: `<ABC xyz="true"/>` this is an empty element but has attributes, so I won't remove this element.
But, only for specific element MNO,
Eg : `<ABC><MNO def="hello"></ABC>`, I want to remove this element MNO. Please help

XSL Code shared below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//@*) and not( normalize-space() )]" />
    <xsl:template match="*/text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am able to remove all empty elements without attributes. As per above, I am unable to remove MNO, which I want to remove

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement please? In the question you say you "do not want to remove this element MNO.", but in your comment you say you do want to remove it. Also, will it be just one specific element you want to (or don't want to) remove, or a list of such elements? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @TimC for clarification. Ya I want to remove only specific element MNO which is empty but has attributes. I don't want to remove any other elements(except MNO) with such properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to add this other template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="MNO[not( normalize-space() )]" priority="2" />
```

The `priority` is needed because it is considered an error to have two templates that match the same thing with the same priority.

Comment: Thanks TimC !! Helped a lot